# Add Logtrail plugin to kibana to see the logs in kibana ui - openshift/origin-aggregated-logging

Tags: docker, openshift-origin

I would like to install the logtrail plugin into the openshift/origin-logging-kibana docker image and build my own image, so I could view my logs properly in kibana ui.

I create a docker file like

```
FROM openshift/origin-logging-kibana:latest  
RUN kibana plugin -i logtrail -u https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/0.1.4/logtrail-4.x-0.1.4.tar.gz  
ADD logtrail.json /opt/kibana/installedPlugins/logtrail/logtrail.json
```

But when i build the image, is showing error

> Sending build context to Docker daemon 7.68 kB
>       Step 1 : FROM openshift/origin-logging-kibana:latest
>       ---> d5e3ce4a04ca
>       Step 2 : RUN kibana plugin -i logtrail -u <--logtrail zip url-->
>       ---> Running in e18ceeb7083c
>       /bin/sh: kibana: command not found
>       The command '/bin/sh -c kibana plugin -i logtrail -u <--logtrail zip url-->   returned a non-zero code: 127

In order to solve this, I gave larsla/kibana-logtrail instead of docker.io/openshift/origin-logging-kibana:latest as docker image to the yml of logging-kibana deployments. When i logged into kibana ui, the logtrailer plugin installed successfully, but kibana couldnt connect to elastic search.

I gave environment variable `ELASTICSEARCH_URL =`

The error in get in log is

> log [22:52:02.901] [warning][elasticsearch] Unable to revive
>   connection: https://logging-es:9200
>       log [22:52:02.902] [warning][elasticsearch] No living connections

Has anyone tried to incorporate logtrail plugin in EFK stack?